# vba for excel macro works in F8-mode but not fully in F5-mode

Tags: vba, excel

I have some  code which creates a snapshot of an excel target range and save it to a .png file. The “real” macro loops over a multiple (user selected) sheets and different range. Everything works fine if I execute the macro in step mode (F8) i.e. step-by-step. The png file is created and contain the snapshot of the range as expected - All good. If I press F5 i.e. play the macro in 1-go as it will ultimately be then I get a blank file i.e. white rectangle. I tested with .bmp format and the file size is the same.

I checked the range being “snaped” using

```
Debug.Print "DEBUG: Target Range is: " & TargetRng.Address(External:=True)
```

and a number of other things and everything appear to be correct.

Any suggestions?
Below is a cutdown version of what I am trying to do. Can anyone replicate this problem?
With Excel 2016, in module called ‘zztesting’

```
Sub test2()

       Dim ir, ic As Integer: ir = 2: ic = 2
        Dim TargetRng As Range

    Set shTargetSheet = Worksheets("sheet1")
    Set TargetRng = shTargetSheet.Range(Cells(ir, ic), Cells(ir + 59, ic + 8))
    CreateSnapShot "sheet1", TargetRng
End Sub

Function CreateSnapShot(sInTargetShtName As String, InTargetRg As Range)

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    sFilePathWithName = objFSO.BuildPath(Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path, sInTargetShtName & ".bmp")

    Set shTargetSheet = Worksheets(sInTargetShtName)

    With shTargetSheet
        InTargetRg.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlPrinter, Format:=xlPicture
        Set objChart = .ChartObjects.Add(1, 1, InTargetRg.Width, InTargetRg.Height)
    End With

        With objChart
            .Chart.Paste
            .Chart.Export Filename:=sFilePathWithName, FilterName:="BMP"
            .Delete
        End With
End Function
```

Comment: `Set TargetRng = shTargetSheet.Range(Cells(ir, ic), Cells(ir + 59, ic + 8))` - you should qualify your `Cells()` with a worksheet object.  If you're running this in a loop then maybe try adding a DoEvents to make sure Excel is keeping up.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As far as I can tell I do not use ActiveSheet in my test. I do use it once in my "real" code once to get the name (of the ActiveSheet).  I also checked that the target workkbook is properly activated and the proper target worksheet is the active one. Mind you I'll do a test (in the full code) to check the name of the active sheet is equal to the name pass to the function (I am sure it is as the file name or the picture is the name of the target worksheet+some other specific string)

Comment: Just check the explict approach for the range definition                                 Set TargetRng = shTargetSht.Range(shTargetSht.Cells(ir, ic), shTargetSht.Cells(ir + 59, ic + 8))  - and it makes no difference . The target workbook and target worksheet are properly "called"/activated. Did a "full" step-by-step test and I get the picture just fine but not in F5-mode

Comment: Use of DoEvents  before .Chart.Export seems to fix the issue. No idea why